# How to resolve SG Client's ENOTFOUND error

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I set up Secure Gateway's destination host as hostname which is `ssldemo`, not an IP address. I started SG Client with `'--net="host"'` option in order to resolve the hostname. Of course, the host operating system can resolve the hostname. Please see the logs of **ping** the hostname. But, SG Client couldn't resolve the hostname and got `"ENOTFOUND"` error when the trx was executed. I tried to add `'--net="host" --add-host "ssldemo:192.168.56.1"'` options, but I got the same error.

Could you please teach me how to resolve `"ENOTFOUND"` error?

```
linux-h4fn:~ #  docker run -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client *GATEWAY_ID* --net="host"
IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Client version 1.1.0
press enter for the command line
[2015-07-06 10:46:50.383] [INFO] The Secure Gateway tunnel is connected
[2015-07-06 10:46:56.824] [INFO] Connection #78 is being established to ssldemo:443
[2015-07-06 10:46:56.845] [INFO] Connection #78 established to ssldemo:443
[2015-07-06 10:46:56.950] [ERROR] Connection #78 to destination ssldemo:443 had error: ENOTFOUND
[2015-07-06 10:46:56.972] [INFO] Connection #78 to ssldemo:443 was closed
[2015-07-06 10:46:58.080] [INFO] Connection #79 is being established to ssldemo:443
[2015-07-06 10:46:58.100] [INFO] Connection #79 established to ssldemo:443
[2015-07-06 10:46:58.296] [ERROR] Connection #79 to destination ssldemo:443 had error: ENOTFOUND

linux-h4fn:~ # ping ssldemo
PING ssldemo (192.168.56.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ssldemo (192.168.56.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.01 ms
64 bytes from ssldemo (192.168.56.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=11.4 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secure gateway service does not recognize the DNS name.  Can you try using the IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: Thank  you Jeff. I succeeded by using the IP address instead of the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the ENOTFOUND error when restarting a Secure Gateway connection that was previously working, it may be a problem with the Docker service itself, and can therefore be resolved by restarting the Docker service on your system.

If the SG client container is still running, kill it:

- **sudo docker ps**
- **sudo docker kill** *containerid*

Restart Docker:

- **sudo service docker restart**

Restart the SG client container:

- **sudo docker run -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client** *clientid*

Don't for get to update your access control list:

- **acl allow** *host*:*port*